# convert http request to kdd cup data format with 41 parameters

Tags: dataset, data-mining, intrusion-detection

- machine learning is done using KDD cup dataset and formed a trained dataset..
- Now I have to check the real time request with the trained dataset..
- for that I have to convert TCP dump data/or http request to KDD CUP data set format(with      41 parameters)

  MY QUESTION IS "HOW CAN I DO THIS CONVERSION ??"

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSL KDD Features from Raw Live Packets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500525/nsl-kdd-features-from-raw-live-packets)

Comment: another duplicate: [How to derive KDD99 Features from DARPA pcap file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090121/how-to-derive-kdd99-features-from-darpa-pcap-file)

Comment: and another: [How to convert KDD 99 dataset to tcpdump format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713680/how-to-convert-kdd-99-dataset-to-tcpdump-format)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the process of how the feature of the *flawed* KDD CUP data set were *exactly* derived is not well documented.

But **it does not reflect real attacks anyway**. Running it on recent data does not make any sense. **These kind of attacks do no longer exist** (if they ever existed beyond script kiddie use in 1997).

## Stop using this data set. NOW.

**It does not reflect any realistic network attack scenario.** If it ever did, that was in 1997 or so; and these attacks can trivially be detected by modern routers. Any machine learning on this data set is *solving a problem that does not exist*. For details, see this earlier answer:

[NSL KDD Features from Raw Live Packets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500525/nsl-kdd-features-from-raw-live-packets/22522174#22522174)

[How to derive KDD99 Features from DARPA pcap file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090121/how-to-derive-kdd99-features-from-darpa-pcap-file/14090551#14090551)

[How to convert KDD 99 dataset to tcpdump format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713680/how-to-convert-kdd-99-dataset-to-tcpdump-format)

(You really should use the *search* function of StackOverflow!)

The real attacks are e.g. SQL injection attacks, and **cannot** be detected on these trivial TCP features, but will require deep packet inspection, or application level firewalls.